# Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State | SignalR, Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, signalr, signalr-hub

I've searched similar topics here, but I still haven't resolved my problem. Maybe somebody can help me with this.

My goal is to display the logs from various services. To do that I am using signalR with vuejs as a client. I want to connect to the group of services on button click and fetch logs. When I click on a different button I want to leave the group and join another.

```
selectItem(name) {
  this.groups.push(name)
  document.getElementById('messageList').innerHTML = ''
      
  const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/logs")
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build()

  if (this.groups.length > 1) {
    let previousGroup = this.groups[this.groups.length - 2]
    connection.invoke("LeaveGroup", previousGroup)
    console.log('leaving group:', previousGroup)
  }

  connection.on("PushEventLog", (message) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.textContent = message
    document.getElementById('messageList').appendChild(div)
  })

  connection.start().then(() => {
    connection.invoke("JoinGroup", name)
    console.log('joining group: ', name)
  })
}
```

On my first joining to group everything works fine, but when I leaving the group and want to join another I receive an error:
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new connection every time `selectItem` runs. You should store the connection object somewhere and only use it after it has started.

Added a couple comments to your code to point out what you're doing wrong.

```
// new connection object
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/logs")
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build()

  if (this.groups.length > 1) {
    let previousGroup = this.groups[this.groups.length - 2]
    // using new connection that hasn't started yet
    connection.invoke("LeaveGroup", previousGroup)
    console.log('leaving group:', previousGroup)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution - I have moved connection and logs to the created hook. Working code below.

```
methods: {
  selectItem(name, i) {
    this.groups.push(name)
    document.getElementById('messageList').innerHTML = ''

    if (this.groups.length > 1) {
      let previousGroup = this.groups[this.groups.length - 2]
      this.connection.invoke("LeaveGroup", previousGroup)
    } else {
      this.connection.invoke("JoinGroup", name)
    }
  }
}
created() {
  this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/logs")
  .build()

  this.connection.start()

  this.connection.on("PushEventLog", (message) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.textContent = message
    document.getElementById('messageList').appendChild(div)
  })
}
```